# I can't use state.filter in Redux reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

So I'm using React-Redux and in my reducer I want to remove a hostname from my state. So from looking around I found out state.filter is a good way to achieve this. However, this is not working, I keep getting an error in my console.

index.js

```
import "babel-polyfill";
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import thunkMiddleware  from 'redux-thunk';
import createLogger from 'redux-logger'
import { HostnameAppContainer } from './components/HostnameApp';
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import hostnameApp from './reducer'
import {fetchHostnames} from './action_creators'

const loggerMiddleware = createLogger()

const store = createStore(
    hostnameApp,
    applyMiddleware(
        thunkMiddleware, // lets us dispatch() functions
        loggerMiddleware // neat middleware that logs actions
    )
)

store.dispatch(fetchHostnames())

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <HostnameAppContainer />
    </Provider>,
document.getElementById('app')
)
;
```

reducer.js

```
export default function(state = {hostnames:[]}, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'FETCH_HOSTNAMES':
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                hostnames: action.hostnames
            })
        case 'DELETE_HOSTNAME':
            return state.filter(hostname =>
                hostname.id !== action.hostnameId
            )
        case 'ADDED_HOSTNAME':
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                hostnames: [
                    ...state.hostnames,
                    action.object
                ]
            })
    }
    return state;
}
```

[image: error]

Thankyou in advance for all suggestions or solutions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your `case 'DELETE_HOSTNAME'` you are calling `state.filter`. Your state at this point will be an `Object` and not an array.

You will probably want to do something like this:

```
case 'DELETE_HOSTNAME':
  return { hostnames: state.hostnames.filter(hostname =>
     hostname.id !== action.hostnameId
  )}
```

Comment: That works perfectly. One more question, so in redux you want to copy your state and then change the copy so you still keep the previous state. How are you 'copying' your old state in this example?

Comment: [The filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). Though the array may be new, it's just a copy of the pointer to each hostname, so be careful mutating the content of hostname.

Comment: @Kujira are you sure? sources?